# SQL query gives me error about mismatch of count of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error:

> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@kelime nvarchar(4000)) SELECT baslik FROM haberEn WHERE baslik' expects the parameter '@kelime', which was not supplied

Why I am getting such an error? How can I fix it?

My SQL command and C# code:

```
   if (requesturl.Contains('-'))
                {
                    string[] aramaParcala = requesturl.Split('-');
                    foreach (string parcalanan in aramaParcala)
                    {
                        aranacak = aranacak + " " + parcalanan;
                    }
                }
                baglanti.Open();
                komut.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                komut.CommandText=
                    " SELECT baslik FROM haberEn WHERE baslik like '%' + @kelime + '%' "+
                    " UNION " +
                    " SELECT yazi FROM haberEn WHERE yazi like  '%' + @kelime + '%' " +
                    " UNION" +
                    " SELECT baslik FROM kaynakEn WHERE baslik like  '%' + @kelime + '%' " +
                    " UNION" +
                    " SELECT yazi FROM kaynakEn WHERE yazi like  '%' + @kelime + '%' Order By baslik ASC";//yazi LIKE '%' + @kelime + '%'
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kelime",aranacak);
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  Your question would be easier to answer if you stripped away the ASP.NET part and just gave us the query, the table structure for the tables; and what the result should  look like (with example data).

Comment: haberEn => English News
kaynakEn => English Publications

Comment: the exception text is quite clear ... you do not have the same amount of columns for each `select` ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair i am selecting same colunms but now i am giving this error:"Additional information: The parameterized query '(@kelime nvarchar(4000)) SELECT baslik FROM haberEn WHERE baslik' expects the parameter '@kelime', which was not supplied."

Comment: @marc_s thanks for enhancing my edits - this question is quite wired and needs some shaping (which I will quit now)

Comment: @OnePage please add additional information to your **QUESTION**!

Comment: @OnePage are you able to write the query w/o a c# context? just a plain sql-stmt with parameters? maybe even a fiddle?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @OnePage your question is quite quirky and completely messed up. Currently it is not clear what your question and problem is. Appropriate context is missing, errors do not correspond to the code you provided ... Please do a massive rework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the column count and data types from `haberEn` and `kaynakEn` should match.

If possible, select only the fields you need, or tell the database how to order them:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM haberEn
union
SELECT col1, col4, col3 FROM kaynakEn
-- note the different order of columns to match those of haberEn.
```

Comment: Okay i select same columns but Now i am giving this Error:"Additional information: The parameterized query '(@kelime nvarchar(4000)) SELECT baslik FROM haberEn WHERE baslik' expects the parameter '@kelime', which was not supplied."

Comment: Sure that `aranacak` isn't `null`?

Comment: Yes `aranacak` isn't null

Comment: Just to be sure, try to replace `aranacak` with `"aaa"`.

Comment: Okay this is working :) But i have two table and link. haberEn => news/example.html and kaynakEn => publications/example.html. How can i understand this and write the repeater ?

Comment: @OnePage: Your question is becoming a moving target. Try to search SE or Google first. If this doesn't help ask a new, complete and clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have different number of fields in the tables?

At least, you should "SELECT" same number of columns from each tables.

Answer (score 0):

Union requires that the tables have the same number of columns.

If all the tables have the same number of columns, check if one of the results is returning empty.